# What does it mean to have a synchronized instance method in Struts 1 Action class?

Tags: methods, struts, synchronized, struts1

i would like to check what it means to have a synchronized instance method in a Struts 1 Action class?

Something like

```
public synchronized String checkAction(){ ... }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the checkAction method is going to be synchronized by the enclosing Object's intrinsic lock (The Action class Object's lock).  So only one thread at a time will be able to access the checkAction method.

In Struts 1 the Action class is not thread safe.  So multiple threads (e.g. servicing multiple requests) will access the same instance of the Action class.  Does the method need to be synchronized?  I'm not sure - only you can tell by what's happening in the method.  So long as it isn't accessing instance variables of the Action class or doing something which can only be done by a single thread at a time, then synchronization is probably not necessary.

Comment: May i paraphrase my interpretation of your answer above to make sure i understand this correctly. It means that since struts 1 Action classes are not thread safe, and because they are singletons, making a method inside of a struts Action class allows access to only 1 thread at a time. thx.

Comment: Making a method synchronized inside the Action class allows access to only 1 thread a time.  If it's not synchronized then as many threads as are thrown at it can come in (generally why you don't use instance variables to hold state in the Action bean)

Comment: Yeah, and synchronized isn't the right solution to this problem (because it creates a bottleneck).  The right solution is to use only local variables.  If you have no instance variables then you don't need synchronisation.  If you want instance variables, then create a helper class, put them in there, and instantiate a helper for each request.